# Pin an absolute element to the edge of a position static max width container

Tags: css

Let's say that inside my body content I have a content boundary element with a max width of 1200px. As the window grows beyond 1200px, the content boundary remains centered at 1200px (see figure 1 below).

Figure 1: 
[image: a website layout with a total width of 1600px, and an inner content of 1200px]
Now I've added a position absolute 'popup' box which sits at the top of the element and is intended to sit at the boundary of the content (right side) (see figure 2).

Figure 2:
[image]
The problems with this:

- There's no implicit relationship between the popup and the content container, nor any elements on the edge of the content boundary. The element sits freely in the markup.
- I cannot make the content boundary position relative without risking regressions in this fairly brittle codebase.

I've determined the easiest way is to butt the popup to the right and then transform backwards to the edge of the content.

Figure 3:

[image]
But the question is, how do I figure out that pixel amount?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## CSS ONLY

Assuming the outer container is the full width of the window, this can be done with a single calc. We can use `vw` to get the exact size of the window.

### Step 1:

*x* = viewport width - content container width

If 100vw = 1600px

e.g. 1600px - 1200px = 400px

The return value of this subtraction is the sum of the space either side of the content container. If the content container is centred, then dividing by two will return the size of one gutter.

### Step 2:

*x* = (viewport width - content container width) / 2

If 100vw = 1600px

e.g. (1600px - 1200px) / 2 = 200px

This value would work to lock the popup to the left side (i.e. if it was positioned with `left: 0;`)

however, we need to make this a negative amount to translate the popup to the left.

### Step 3:

Multiply by -1 to make the number negative

*x* = ((viewport width - content container width) / 2) * -1

e.g. ((1600px - 1200px) / 2) * -1 = -200px

### Step 4: All in together now

`transform: translateX(calc(((100vw - 1200px) / 2) * -1));`

For a demo: https://codepen.io/3stacks/pen/wjExrw